# Accessing Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report deployed to the SQL Server Reporting Services web interface.
From machines in the same domain i have no problem accessing the report.
When i have tried to access the report from home (not on the same network) i succeeded too.

The problem is with one of our customers not able to vies his report.
He gets a page with nothing in it. like basic html or resources not found.
since i'm a new user i can't post here the image itself.
i'm leaving here my mail so if you intrested with helping and want to see the img i'll forward it to you.

gilad.sagiv@mobile-mx.com

the steps i took were:

1.create a new user in the windows where the reporting service installed.
i gave it the same group as the general reprot user (i want this user to see only a            specific reprot)

2.in the reporting servie admin i have gave this user the same role as the general reporting service user.

i thought that will be enough but it seems that it is not.
any ideas ? 
Thanks Giald

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I will post as an answer.

1. The first thing you should do, if you didn't, is check if he can see the report in other machines than his.
2. When we have permission issues, the SSRS gives a message saying the user can't access the Report due permission issues and not a blank page or any other kind of error, so I'm thinking this is not a permission problem.
3. Other thing that could be is since you are giving him access to a specific Report you are probably giving him the direct URL to the Report, check if the URL has changed.

Comment: thanks for the reply. he was able to see the report in other machines. and the url wasn't changd. thanks though

Comment: Nice, now you know the problem is with his machine and has nothing to do with the Reporting Services.

Comment: great .... i'm not sure if you get to work with "customers" - it is always YOUR problem unless you give them the exact answer. would you mind emailing me so i can forward the png - maybe it will shed some light on this issue ?

Comment: I would check his machine internet security settings and see if it's blocking anything from the Reporting Services. In IE make sure the Reporting Services URL is in trusted sites. In IE go to Tools>Internet Settings>Security>Trusted Sites> Sites> Add the URL and click ADD.

Comment: i will ask him to make this two checks.

Comment: he now tells me that from his laptop he can view the report when within his organization and fails when browsing from his home.any ideas?

Comment: And finally we know the problem is his home connection, unfortunately I really don't know what could be the problem, if he could see the Report at home and not at office, I would say it's a internet security matter with his office, but in this case... what could be blocking his access to the Report in his home internet? Suposing his home internet has no specific internet security settings.

Comment: I doubt that's the problem, but it worth the check. I've experienced some people whom use their machine both at home and office to have internet problems when they get home or office, this is due manually Proxy settings. Supposing his office has a Proxy setting which has to be set manually everytime he get in his office and when he gets home he has to remove those settings in order to use his home internet.

Comment: thanks for all your help Turque. i will keep investigating it. i need to find out why he can see the structure  of the page but not the report itself and other resources such as images.